# In Coco (2017), Is "Papá Julio" Coco's husband?

Tags: plot-explanation, coco

In Coco (2017), when Miguel meets his family, and through all the movie, he always calls his family members like "Tia Rosita" (aunt Rosita), "Tia Victoria" (aunt Victoria) and so on. The only one that he calls "Papá" (dad) is "Papá Julio" (dad Julio).

Since the "family tree" that is shown in the movie begins with "Mama Imelda" and her daughter Coco, we can safely assume there are no more kids to "Mama Imelda", therefore all this "tios y tias" (uncles and aunts) must be related to Coco.

Is "Papá Julio" Coco's husband? and therefore, Are the "tios and tias" Julio and Coco's kids?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to this Wikia](https://cocomovie.fandom.com/wiki/Julio):

> **Julio, or known as Papa Julio was Coco's late husband**. He can get very excited and nervous about things but he always puts family first and tries to help out. Due to her failing memory, Coco sometimes calls Miguel Julio, possibly because of his resemblance to him.

There is apparently a family tree in the novelization of the movie, [***A Story about Music, Shoes and Family***](https://books.disney.com/book/coco-middle-grade-novel/). You can find several online, though most seem to be rather limited. This is one of the more elaborate ones, as found on [MountainLygon's DevianArt page](https://www.deviantart.com/mountainlygon/art/Rivera-Family-Tree-Corrected-758083139):

[image: Rivera Family Tree - Corrected]

They note:

> When third parties publish promotional and supplemental materials for a film typos are not uncommon. These errors range from misspelled names to incorrect labels. Such is the case for the Rivera family tree as presented in the Coco novelization, "A Story about Music, Shoes and Family." On that family tree, Gloria is incorrectly listed as the daughter of Franco and Elena, while Carmen is listed as Berto's wife. This led to some confusion as to which tía is which, since in that same novel, certain lines of dialogue the audience associated with Berto's wife are credited to Gloria. So fans asked director Lee Unkrich which tía was which. He pointed to the woman with the bun in her hair and said her name was Gloria, and then to the heavyset woman and said her name was Carmen. He did NOT specify which of them was a blood Rivera. But he didn't need to. Any discerning fan who pondered that information long enough would come to the conclusion that the family tree (again, published by a third party without Unkrich or Molina's input) is wrong.